# Not able to get hidden contents of a website

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-3.5, spyder

I am trying to scrape a website with the help of BeautifulSoup. I am not able to get the contents of the website but it is on the source code when  I inspect the site.

```
import requests
import urllib 

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url1 = 'https://recruiting.ultipro.com/usg1006/JobBoard/dfc53730-57d1-3460-336f-ddafabd108f3/?q=&o=postedDateDesc'

response1 = get(url1)

print(response1.text[:500])
html_soup1 = BeautifulSoup(response1.text, 'html.parser')
type(html_soup1)

all_info1 = html_soup1.find("div", {"data-bind": "foreach: opportunities"})
all_info1

all_automation1 = all_info1.find_all("div",{"data-automation":"opportunity"})

all_automation1
```

In the source code there is "job-title", "location" and "description" and other details but I am not able to see the same details in the html contents.

Comment: which python version are you using? Tag the question with that particular version of Python.

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal it is Python 3.5.2

Comment: Did you try to replace `all_automation1` line by `print(all_automation1)`? Cause I do and it works.. _(I hope I'm wrong here..)_

Comment: yes and I got the contents of the source code, but as i said in the post information like "Job title","location","description", etc.. is not there. But it is there in the source code

Comment: You can see it in the source code because even if they are dynamically generated they exist there but when you make a http request then it can't catch that as your request is processed before the time taken for the browser to load it's content.

Answer (score 0):

You should try like this or anything similar to fetch the title from that page:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://recruiting.ultipro.com/usg1006/JobBoard/dfc53730-57d1-3460-336f-ddafabd108f3/?q=&o=postedDateDesc')
time.sleep(3)       #let the browser load it's content
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'lxml')
for item in soup.select("h3 .opportunity-link"):
    print(item.text)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: I have downloaded the Chromedriver and executed your suggested code but I am getting an error:   WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.34.522940 (1a76f96f66e3ca7b8e57d503b4dd3bccfba87af1),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64).

Comment: Have you tried a single site to parse data from using selenium? If it is, then there is no reason for the above code to break.

Comment: yes I have tried with single site only, when I ran the code first it opened the command prompt chromedriver then opened web site which have something like data;